# Updating nested array not working - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm using this query :

```
Model.update(
    {_id: req.params.questions_id, "doc.questionSets.$._id": req.params.set_id},
    {$pushAll: {"questions": req.body}},
    {upsert:true},
    function(err, questions){
        console.log("err", err);
        console.log("err", questions);
    }
)
```

The route call :

```
localhost:3131/api/v0.1/charting/questions/56cff03e9ff240192da2fa34/set/56cff04e9ff240192da2fa3a/add-new-question
```

where : `charting/questions/:questions_id/set/:set_id/add-new-question`

The document data :

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cff03e9ff240192da2fa34"),
    "questionSets" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Physical exam questions",
            "_id" : ObjectId("56cff03e9ff240192da2fa35"),
            "questions" : [ 
                {
                    "question" : "What is love?",
                    "answer" : "",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("56cff03e9ff240192da2fa39")
                }
            ]
        }, 

        {
            "name" : "Brain questions",
            "_id" : ObjectId("56cff04e9ff240192da2fa3a"),
            "questions" : [ 
                {
                    "question" : "What is love?",
                    "answer" : "",
                    "_id" : ObjectId("56cff04e9ff240192da2fa3e")
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-02-26T06:26:39.330Z")
}
```

And I want to push this JSON object to `questionSets[0].questions` :

```
[

    {
        "question" : "Added 1?"
    }
]
```

But the query returns **{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }** and the document has not been updated. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With the data

```
> db.questions.find().forEach(printjson)
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56d0143bd43e3500f6768488"),
        "questionSets" : [
                {
                        "name" : "q1",
                        "_id" : "1",
                        "question" : [
                                {
                                        "question" : "here",
                                        "answer" : "dd",
                                        "_id" : "1"
                                }
                        ]
                },
                {
                        "name" : "q2",
                        "_id" : "2",
                        "question" : [
                                {
                                        "question" : "you",
                                        "answer" : "cc",
                                        "_id" : "2"
                                }
                        ]
                }
        ]
}
```

Run the command

```
> db.questions.update({'questionSets._id': '1'}, 
                      {$pushAll: {
                                'questionSets.$.question': [
                                                    {question: 'you', 
                                                     answer: 'are',
                                                     _id: '3'}]}})

WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
```

Comment: Hi. It returned this error. `{ name: 'MongoError',
  message: 'Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.',
  driver: true,
  ok: 1,
  n: 0,
  code: 16650,
  errmsg: 'Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.',
  writeConcernError: 
   { code: 16650,
     errmsg: 'Cannot apply the positional operator without a corresponding query field containing an array.' } }
`

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx, sorry for previous careless, is the value of `req.body` an array?

Comment: Yes it looks like this.  `[ {"question" : "Added 1?"} ]`

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx, I have updated my answer with my test codes. please take a look, hope it could help...

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx, Is this `"doc.questionSets.$._id": req.params.set_id` work well in your test?

Comment: I dont have a test, but when querying `"doc.questionSets.$._id": req.params.set_id` returns null.

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx, could please place your previous query condition as `"questionSets._id": req.params.set_id`?

Comment: It doesnt work either `"questionSets._id": req.params.set_id`

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx, is there really same `_id` document with `req.params.set_id`? or to check `req.params.set_id` is valid `_id`? Or maybe should it convert to `ObjectId` throgh `ObjectId(req.params.set_id)`?

Comment: All id is valid and converting them to `ObjectId` doesnt work either :/

Comment: @TheGreenFoxx, that is weird... maybe you can post your code in one `gist`, or something else so that I can investigate it ...

Comment: Sure I will. Maybe this is a bug or something. Thanks very much for you time.